# I'm trying to use socket.io to send a message from the server to everyone that is connected, but the clients don't receive it, why is that?

Tags: sockets, node.js, socket.io

Basically, I want to send every change that happens in the game world to every client, and I thought I would do it like this:

**SERVER:**

```
/*init*/
    var http = require("http");
    var io = require("socket.io");
    var game_server = http.createServer(handler);
    game_server.listen(8080);
    var game_socket = io.listen(game_server);

    game_socket.configure(function() 
    {
      game_socket.set('log level', 1);
    });
```

Later on in the game, when someone changes the map, I send this to everyone (well, apparently not):

```
game_socket.sockets.send("newStatic", {"img":s.img, "id": s.id, "rect": s.rect, "health": s.health});
```

**CLIENT:**

```
 self.socket.on("newStatic", function(data)
 {
      self.pl.world.push(data);
      console.log(data);
 });
```

This, unfortunately, never get's called.

Comment: I don't really think that's the best way to do it, should look at the docs http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Of course not, it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.IO uses `emit` for custom messages: http://socket.io/#how-to-use

You want to do

```
game_socket.sockets.emit("newStatic", {"img":s.img, "id": s.id, "rect": s.rect, "health": s.health});
```